# Me falla la terminal de python en VS Code

Tags: python, powershell

Estoy aprendiendo python, y el curso que estoy tomando utiliza VSC como editor principal, por lo que cambiarlo ahora no me parece una opción.

El punto es que estoy haciendo todo tal cual el video y la terminal me da error de sintaxis. Incluso he puesto un simple `print ("hola mundo")` y me vuelve a dar error de sintaxis.

Se arregla temporalmente cuando cierro todo el spacework y creo un archivo nuevo, entonces ejecuta sin problemas y luego se vuelve a romper por eso sé que es un problema con la terminal.

¿Alguien tiene idea de qué puede estar pasando y cómo puedo resolverlo? Muchas gracias a todos.

PD: La versión de python que estoy usando es la 3.10

Comment: Cual es el error completo?

Comment: Hola Christian me he dado cuenta de que limpiando la terminal el error desaparece, ¿Crees que sea eso? soy una persona curiosa me gustaría saber por qué tengo que limpiar la terminal cada tanto.

Comment: No creo que se deba a eso. Para dar con el verdadero fallo debemos conocer mejor tu situación y apartir de ahí poder explicar que es lo que ocurre. Sin más no te puedo decir que es lo que ocurre

Comment: Puedes probar a cambiar la terminal en `Configuración - Características - Terminal` y allí seleccionar `Integrated › Default Profile: Windows: Command Prompt`, a ver si así te deja de dar el error y sales de la duda...